# How to zoom and pan a photo in macOS with a non-Apple mouse?

Tags: macos, photos, zoom, pan

It seems it is impossible to pan and zoom in a photo in macOS easily. In Windows using the scroll wheel someone can zooms in where the mouse cursor is and using left click it is possible to pan the photo.

Is this an issue with macOS itself or the default photo viewer in Mac?
How can I zoom into the area where the mouse cursor is? How can I pan the photo afterwards?

I do not want to zoom in using the accessibility tool and I use a Logitech mouse. My Mac is Monterey 12.6.5.

**Edit**
I have finally found that <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> allows to pan the photo. However, I cannot still zoom in where the mouse cursor is using the scroll wheel the same way it is done in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Mac doesn't really use scroll to zoom, other than for accessibility.

Your main zoom Controls are  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>+</kbd>  and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd> . These will both centre on your current mouse position.

Scroll is then either scroll-wheel for vertical, shift/scroll for horizontal, or just grab & drag.

I just realised by 'default photo viewer' you meant Preview, not Photos.
Yes, that uses  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd>  for grab, similar to Photoshop.

Comment: I noticed that most Software in Mac also do not use the scroll to zoom. Is it something Apple have to implement first so that Software developers can use? I think Digikam or Darktable could zoom with scroll though.

Comment: @MOON - Yeah, graphics apps tend to do it; Adobe etc do too. The rest tend to be Cmd/+ or -

Answer (score 0):

If your mouse has any side buttons, you might try the little utility that is [Mac Mouse Fix](https://mousefix.org/). This can be achieved:

- Holding one side button while sliding the wheel to simulate pinch.
- Holding one side button or another while moving the mouse to simulate pan.
- Holding one side button or yet another while sliding the wheel to simulate pan, with shift to change directions.

It effectively makes your mouse a trackpad.